# PHP-Mysql error with %

Tags: php, mysql

I wrote a very simple mysql line for my very simple search bar that searches keywords, but I ran through an error. (I have a feeling it's because of the length of the search)

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM entries WHERE name='%".$search."%' ";
```

works, but

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM entries WHERE desc='%".$search."%' ";
```

doesn't.

In the database, name has around 20 characters, and desc has around 700. I checked spelling and everything, it just outputs an error.

**Does it not work because it has too many characters to scan through?**

Thanks a lot (in advance)!

Comment: 2 Problems: 1. You do no error checking (otherwise this question qould not have been asked at all or in a different way), 2. you MIGHT be a target to SQL injection. You should use prepared statements or, at least, the `mysql_real_escape_string()` function.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure how you would do error checking on Mysql? (btw, yeah, I protect my SQL but I didn't include it in my examples thats all)

Comment: Well, if you notice that a function call went wrong, you call e.g. [`mysql_error()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php) if you use the old interface. The mysqli and PDO interfaces surely have a similiar function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`desc` is mysql key word, you need to quote it, and you should use `LIKE` instead of `=`, and make sure your `$search` has been escaped.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM entries WHERE `desc` LIKE '%".$search."%' ";
```

Comment: Oh, I almost forgot about LIKE, and thanks a lot for that answer!